# Where can I find mass transit directions with times for Berlin?

Tags: planning, public-transport, germany, maps, berlin

Usually I check Google Maps, but it doesn't have routing or train times for Berlin. Is there an official trip planner? Bonus points for suggesting mobile applications as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Maps now supports mass transit navigation in Berlin, so there's no need to use external apps.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You want [bvg.de](http://www.bvg.de/). It has [English](http://www.bvg.de/index.php/en/index.html) and German versions, and if you visit the site on a mobile device it'll offer a mobile optimised version. They have an excellent trip planner, covering regional trains, S-Bahn, U-Bahn, Bus, Tram and walking. You can also download various network maps for offline use.

In addition to the website, there are a number of apps available for mobile which work with their data. I quite like the DB Navigator for the iPad, which covers all of the Berlin BVG transport too, but I've seen lots of others in use too!

Comment: There's also a pretty nice [trip planner at VBB](http://www.vbb.de/en/index.html) ("the public transport authority covering the federal states of Berlin and Brandenburg – the capital area of Germany"). I wonder what the difference between that and the BVG planner is...

Comment: In theory I'd guess that the VBB one would do everything that the BVG one does, and Brandenburg too. However, BVG seems happy to give me directions into Brandenburg, so I wonder if they now just run off the same dataset and the distinction has gone?

Comment: @Gagravarr: They use the same query syntax in the browser address bar so they seem use the same software and most likely the same data set too.